# How to update same array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

Below mention my reducer code. the case is I implemented before if the same value come it not push to the array. but now I want to if the same value come it update the previous value. then not push the same value to the array.

This is my code,

```js
export function reducer(
      state: IDeviceState = initialState,
      action: DeviceActions.AllDeviceActions
    ): IDeviceState {
      switch (action.type) {
        case DeviceActions.GET_DEVICE_BY_ID_SUCCESS: {
          const { payload } = action;
          const devices = Array.isArray(payload)
            ? payload
                .map(pushBranches)
                .flat()
                .filter((device) => device !== null)
            : [pushBranches(payload)].filter((device) => device !== null);

          const updatedDevices = devices.filter((device) => {
            const existingDevice = state.devices.find(
              (d) => d.result?.unitId === device.result.unitId
            );

            return !existingDevice;
          });

          return {
            ...state,
            devices: state.devices.concat(updatedDevices),
            loading: false,
            loaded: true,
            error: null,
          };
        }
        default: {
          return state;
        }
      }
    }

    function pushBranches(devices: any) {
      if (devices.result) {
        return devices;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: please refactor your question to make it more clear. I would suggest adding case examples too

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your state includes an array of objects, each having a key (which I guess from the code is `unitId`). The action you are handling here can pass an array of such objects in its payload, and you want to perform an "upsert", which inserts or updates the state by matching on `unitId`.

You can break an upsert down into two stages:

- remove from the state any object whose `unitId` matches at least one of the objects in the payload
- add all the objects from the payload to the state

By the way, `GET_DEVICE_BY_ID_SUCCESS` does not seem to be a very good name for an action. It sounds more like a name for a method of retrieving information without making a change to the state. Actions exist specifically to modify state. I'd call this action `DEVICE_UPSERT` or something like that.

Your action is also able to accept a payload of a single object rather than an array. You could simplify that by saying at the start:

```js
const payloadArray = Array.isArray(payload) ? payload : [payload];
```

Then you can operate on `payloadArray` knowing it is always an array.

To perform phase one of your upsert, the deletion of existing devices, you can adapt your `updatedDevices` declaration. Instead of filtering the payload against the state, filter the state against the payload:

```
const remainingDevices = state.devices.filter(stateDevice => devices.every(
    d => d.result?.unitId !== stateDevice.result?.unitId
));
```

So `remainingDevices` is an array of just the devices that remain after we removed those devices included in the payload. The `every` method on `Array` checks that the lambda is true for every element of the array, so for a `stateDevice` to remain in `remainingDevices` it must not have the same `unitId` as any payload device.

And to that array, we can `concat` the payload's devices to get the final new state.